# Когда не стоит использовать итератор?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Когда использование паттерна итератор уместно, а в каких случаях нежелательно?

Какие подводные камни скрывает паттерн?

Например, у меня есть класс для чтения строк из файла:

```
public class FormattedFileReader{
    private readonly string _path;

    // ...     

    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadFromFile(){

        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(_path)){
            yield return GetFormattedValue(line);
        }
    }

    private string GetFormattedValue(string initial){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: То что вы показали не является паттерном итератор. Реализуйте в своем каком-нибудь классе интерфейс `IEnumerator<T>` вот тогда это можно будет считать паттерном итератор.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий и размытый. А ваш код можно заменить одной строкой `var data = File.ReadLines(path)`, поэтому у меня встречный вопрос: зачем вам понадобилось писать так много кода, если можно было это сделать короче и проще?

Comment: @AK, не, там же еще `Select(GetFormattedValue)`

Comment: Это же linq. Пусть поставит точку и допишет своё выражение. Вон, если мне нужно прочитать файл, откинуть первую строку, разбить через split, обработать каждую строку - можно спокойно написать `File.ReadAllLines(sourceFileName).Skip(1).Select(x => x.Split(';')).Select(...` а не писать для этого многословные итераторы. Есть задача - нужно идти к ней кратчайшим путём, не отвлекаясь на бойлерплейт.

Comment: @AK предположим, что вам нужно инкапсулировать логику обработки строк. Я специально не писал код метода `GetFormattedValue` потому что там может быть много логики. Класс `FormattedFileReader` выступает в роли Proxy

Comment: Не вижу подобного предположения в поставленном вопросе или в приведённом коде, но допустим. Попробуйте написать два варианта кода - на итераторах и на linq, сравните какой вариант будет понятнее и проще.

Comment: @Vadim Prokopchuk, что-то мне подсказывает, что форматированием должна заниматься другая сущность, которая передаётся в конструктор класса FormattedFileReader, который, кстати, можно и переименовать после этого.

Comment: @AK, я например, писал итератор, читающий текстовый файл заданным кол-вом строк. Чтобы прочитал из файла, например, 40 строк или меньше, если их меньше и вернул их. Так что такой класс иногда имеет смысл.

Comment: @CasperSC тут разве указана конкретная реализация? Вы пишете комментарий не по вопросу.

Comment: @Vadim Prokopchuk, ага, как и почти все комментарии выше. Окей.

Comment: У вас класс совмещает две ответственности: а) он читает б) он форматирует, т.е. это не класс для чтения строк, это класс чтения строк с последующим форматированием. Поэтому замечание о нарушении SRP вполне уместно.

Comment: @AK, есть мнение что некоторые понимают SRP неверно ;-)

Comment: Это пример! Мне написать конкретную реализацию конструктора и метода? Вы обсуждаете принцип ответственности, а не итератор...

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, хорошо. Я бы не использовал этот паттерн там, где нужно быстро бегать по массиву, где нужна производительность. Я бы там не использовал foreach в том числе. Для остального не вижу проблем.

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, я бы не использовал ещё такой подход там, где лучше не держать открытым соединение, например, с БД или с чем-то ещё - yield return, я об этом моменте. И это если тот, кто принимает данные из этого метода может долго с ними работать не возвращая управление.

Comment: @CasperSC Вооот, в последнем комментарии иммено то, что хотелось улышать. Спасибо :)

Comment: @CasperSC Вы можете оформить ответ

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, ок. Сделаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Что пишут про итераторы на MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-20)

Скажу своё мнение насчёт использования итератора.

Когда бы не использовал я:

- Если нужна производительность, а именно быстрый обход какой-то
  коллекции с индексатором, а значит не использовал бы `foreach`
- Если итератор использует внутри метода `IEnumerator<T>
  GetEnumerator()` `yield return` и при этом нам лучше не держать открытым соединение, например, с БД длительное время, ведь мы точно не можем быть уверенными, что внутри вызывающего цикла `foreach` мы в приемлемое время обойдём всю коллекцию и закроем соединение или обойдёт её кто-то другой, не посвещённый в наши планы относительно быстрого обхода коллекции.

Примеры, где я считаю использование итератора очень даже уместным:

Обход части коллекции

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс-итератор для прохода по части исходной коллекции, реализующей <see cref="IReadOnlyList{T}"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"> Тип элементов коллекции. </typeparam>
public struct SubListIterator<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyList<T> _original;
    private readonly int _start;

    public SubListIterator(IReadOnlyList<T> original, int start, int length)
    {
        if (original == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(original));
        }

        if (start < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(start));
        }

        if (length < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length));
        }

        if (start + length > original.Count)
        {
            throw new Exception(
                "The range exceeds the size of the original IReadOnlyList " +
                $"({nameof(start)} + {nameof(length)} = {(start + length).ToString()}, size of IReadOnlyList = {original.Count}).");
        }

        Length = length;
        _original = original;
        _start = start;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= Length)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }

            return _original[_start + index];
        }
    }

    public int Length { get; }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            yield return _original[_start + i];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Метод-расширение для итератора

```
public static class IReadOnlyListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<SubListIterator<T>> GetPart<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> list, int partSize)
    {
        int newPartSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += newPartSize)
        {
            newPartSize = partSize + i > list.Count ? list.Count - i : partSize;
            yield return new SubListIterator<T>(list, i, newPartSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Чтение из файла, если нам не принципиально закрывать это файл быстро

```
/// <summary>
/// Класс для чтения из файла данных по частям.
/// </summary>
public class TextFileIterator : IEnumerable<IReadOnlyList<string>>
{
    private readonly string _pathToFile;
    private readonly int _maxLines;
    private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;
    private readonly Encoding _encoding;

    public TextFileIterator(string pathToFile, int maxLines, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        Debug.Assert(maxLines > 0);
        Debug.Assert(pathToFile != null);
        Debug.Assert(cancellationToken != null);

        _pathToFile = pathToFile;
        _maxLines = maxLines;
        _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;

        if (encoding == null)
        {
            encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        }
        _encoding = encoding;
    }

    public IEnumerator<IReadOnlyList<string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        using (var file = new StreamReader(_pathToFile, _encoding))
        {
            var lines = new List<string>(_maxLines);

            do
            {
                lines.Clear();
                string line = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < _maxLines; i++)
                {
                    if ((line = file.ReadLine()) == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        yield break;
                    }

                    lines.Add(line);
                }

                if (lines.Count > 0)
                {
                    yield return lines.ToArray();
                }

                if (line == null)
                {
                    break;
                }

            } while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```